# JPA Hibernate MySQL insert entity deadlock without cascade

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, locking

I have the code below with all necessary details:

```
// This method is in UserService, marked with @Transactional
// Called when we insert a new user into the application.
// MySQL DB tables are: `user` and `user_attempt`
// ISOLATION LEVEL = READ-COMMITTED
@Override
public void insert(User entity) {

    // user_attempt has no knowledge of user
    UserAttempt uA = instanceNewUserAttempt();

    userAttemptDao.insertEntity(uA);    // uA is assigned an AUTO_INCREMENT from MySql

    // Unidirectional
    // @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    // @JoinColumn(name = "user_attempt_id", nullable = false)
    // private UserAttempt userAttempt;
    entity.setUserAttempt(uA);

    // No locks until here
    super.insert(entity);   // Now here 2 locks are generated in the DB, why?
    // Code blocks and does not go further. super just calls em.persist(...)
}
```

[image: Locks]

P.S. Cascades for me is not a solution!

**EDIT 1**

Added new screen with info
[image]

**EDIT 2**

Tried to debug Hibernate, and the block does happen at this line of code inside org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate:

```
session.getJdbcCoordinator().getResultSetReturn().executeUpdate( insert );
```

**EDIT 3**

Changed the code to be like below, and now it works, but now the difference is that in DB for User I must put user_attempt_id to allow NULL, which conceptually must not happen as User and UserAttempt must exist only in combination:

```
// This method is in UserService, marked with @Transactional
// Called when we insert a new user into the application.
// MySQL DB tables are: `user` and `user_attempt`
// ISOLATION LEVEL = READ-COMMITTED
@Override
public void insert(User entity) {

    UserAttempt uA = instanceNewUserAttempt();

    userAttemptDao.insertEntity(uA);

    super.insert(entity);

    // Unidirectional
    // @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    // @JoinColumn(name = "user_attempt_id", nullable = true)
    // private UserAttempt userAttempt;
    entity.setUserAttempt(uA);
}
```

**Conclusions:**

1. If I want to have NOT NULL constraint in DB, then I can't use Hibernate the way I want, it simply does not work. (Meaning inserting both entities in same transaction and marking the relationship)
2. If I drop the idea to have DB constraint NOT NULL for user_attempt_id and insert entities separately, then in the same transaction I do the relation, then it works, but then in DB is a logical gap.

Comment: is this on a case where `entity.getUserAttempt();` returns `null`, not null, or both?

Comment: both, it does not matter, the problem is not there. I will delete that part to not create confusion

Comment: i was asking because your 2nd screen shot contains remarks about a failed key constraint, which seems to indicate that the `uA` entity isn't persisted at that time (just a wild guess, never seen this type of logging before - may all be normal)

Comment: I have the strong impression that the `super.insert()` is running in a transaction of its own, a different one than the `insert()` you're showing. I conclude this because the switching of lines (in your edit 3) should not make a difference as long as both lines are in the same transaction: the "commit" of the entity would only happen when the method returns, and `userAttempt` property would be set either way. Can you show the code for `super.insert()` and its transactional annotations?

Comment: Not the switching itself and only made the code to work, but the addition of nullable = true and removal of optional = false did, as now User allows null UserAttempt. Also, super just calls em.persist(entity), and the current transaction is joined (debugged that, single transaction found, or I debugger wrong).

Comment: How about `userAttemptDao.insertEntity()`? If that is using a different `entityManager`, then the current one will not be aware that `uA` is already persisted. Can you try to do something like `uA = em.find(uA.class, uA.getId())` right after it, or to simply put the persist inline instead of invoking the dao.